# save serialized object in phone memory

Tags: android

Here i have some data which i want to store in phone memory and retrieve when necessary

here is the code:

```
 public void saveObject(Person p){
     try
     {

         FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("save_object.bin", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
         ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);


        oos.writeObject(p); // write the class as an 'object'
        oos.flush(); // flush the stream to insure all of the information was written to 'save_object.bin'
        oos.close();// close the stream
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
        Log.v("Serialization Save Error : ",ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
     }
}

public Object loadSerializedObject(File f)
{
    try
    {
         FileInputStream fin = openFileInput("save_object.bin");

        Object o = fin.read();
        return o;

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    Log.v("Serialization Read Error : ",ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

using sdcard also i am receiving error as `/mnt/sdcard/save_object.bin (Permission denied)`

retrieving by

```
Person person1 = (Person)loadSerializedObject(getDir("save_object.bin",Context.MODE_PRIVATE));//get the serialized object from the sdcard and caste it into the Person class.
```

class:

```
public class Person implements Serializable 
{
    String username="";
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 46543445; 

    public void setusername(String username)
    {
        this.username = username;
    }





    public String getusername()
    {
        return username;
    }



}
```

i have used

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

how could i store this in phone memory @Could somebody help me @Thanks

Comment: Does Person implements Serializable?

Comment: all the elements inside person are serializable?

Comment: what error do you get. Also you miss ois.close();

Comment: Instenad of hardcode the path, retrieve the root with Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

Comment: File file = new File(Environmnet.getExternalStorageDirectory(), save_object.bin); FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);  ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream((fos)

Comment: but do you get this error when you try to serialize or deserialize person?

Comment: but do you get this error when you try to write or read the object from sdcard ? Is your sdcard mountent on your pc?

Comment: what does "in phone memory" mean for you?

Comment: @blackbelt is it possible to store

Comment: try this way, when you write: FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("save_object.bin", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); When you read it FileInputStream fin = openFileInput("save_object.bin");

Comment: @blackbelt i have edited my code, i am getting the same error no such file or directory

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30384/discussion-between-blackbelt-and-priya2134412)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have not a valid mountpoint `/sdcard`, You have to use the application cache for store your object.

Retrieve the InputStream this way:

```
FileInputStream fin = openFileInput("save_object.bin");
```

and your FileOutputStream this way:

```
 FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("save_object.bin", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

to deserialize the object change your code this way:

```
FileInputStream fin = openFileInput("save_object.bin");
 ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
 Object o = ois.readObject();
```